# How to add attribute table to new shapefile using OGR?

Tags: python, shapefile, attribute-table, ogr

i have made a new shapefile from the original shapefile , and now i want to copy the attribute table from the original shapefile to the new select shapefile , but i don't know how to do that?

```
import ogr,os,sys,ogr

Datasource_Parks = 'ArcCR500_v32/ChranenaUzemi.shp'

Direction_Result_Shp = 'ArcCR500_v32/Result.shp'
Direction_Result_Dbf="ArcCR500_v32/Table.dbf"


Open_Parks = ogr.Open(Datasource_Parks)
layer_park = Open_Parks.GetLayer(0)

SQL = "NAZEV_ASCI = 'Krkonossky narodni park'"

layer_park.SetAttributeFilter(SQL)

Number_Of_Park = layer_park.GetFeatureCount()

Driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI shapefile")

if os.path.exists(Direction_Result_Shp):
    Driver.DeleteDataSource(Direction_Result_Shp)

Dataset = Driver.CreateDataSource(Direction_Result_Shp)

New_Layer = Dataset.CreateLayer(Direction_Result_Shp, geom_type= ogr.wkbPolygon)

number = 0
for i in range(0, Number_Of_Park):
    H = layer_park.GetNextFeature()
    H_geometry = H.GetGeometryRef()

    New_Layer.CreateFeature(H)

Dataset.Destroy()
```

[image: attribute table form the original shape file,"ChranenaUzemni.shp]

[image: New shape file with no attribute table]

Comment: You can't do that directly. What you need to do is Join by Attributes, hide the fields you don't want, and 'save as' a new shapefile. For this to work you *must* have a unique field matching between tables - it can be numeric (integer) or text but shouldn't be float/double.

Comment: Why just you dont use selection of your feature and then use datasource.CopyLayer and copy the feature into the new shapefile?

Answer (score 3):

if you wanted to stick with the loop (maybe to modify attribute names in some way) - you could also do something like:

```
    #after creating New_Layer
    featdef = ogr.Feature(layer_park.GetLayerDefn())
    feat1 = layer_park.GetNextFeature() #read first feature to get attributes
    for i in range(feat1.GetFieldCount()):
        fieldDef = feat1.GetFieldDefnRef(i)
        New_Layer.CreateField(fieldDef)

    layer_park.ResetReading() #back to first feature of original layer
    for feat in layer_park:
        New_Layer.CreateFeature(feat)
        feat = None
```

note - you don't have to pull the geometry separately

Answer (score 1):

I have made some edits in your script. I changed the For cycle into Copy Layer method. Try it if you want. This method preserve the attributes as you want.

```
import ogr,os,sys

Datasource_Parks = 'ArcCR500_v32/ChranenaUzemi.shp'

Direction_Result_Shp = 'ArcCR500_v32/Result.shp'
Direction_Result_Dbf="ArcCR500_v32/Table.dbf"

Open_Parks = ogr.Open(Datasource_Parks)
layer_park = Open_Parks.GetLayer(0)

############################## add variable 'location' into SQL
location = 'Krkonossky narodni park'
SQL = "NAZEV_ASCI = " + locaion

layer_park.SetAttributeFilter(SQL)

Number_Of_Park = layer_park.GetFeatureCount()

############################## edit
####### make output variable (only first word)
output_file = "output_" + location.split(" ")[0] + ".shp"

driver_out = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
ds_out = driver_out.CreateDataSource(output_file)

lyr_out = ds_out.CopyLayer(layer_park, output_file.split(".")[0])

lyr_out.SyncToDisk()
ds_out.SyncToDisk()
############################## end


Dataset.Destroy()
```

Comment: thanks for your help,but there is problem when i run the script, for the first time it works but when i run it again, i faced with this error:AttributeError:'NoneType'object has no attribute 'CopyLayer', do you know have can i solve this.

Comment: You have to make "output_file.shp" as a variable. You cant create the same layer again, thats because varable is necessary. I have made some changes in script above.

Comment: Am I right that you want to export your location one by one to new shapefile?

Comment: so let me tell you my task. i have a shape file with the two type of name(National park and park in CR) and also a dem file . so i have to first select the type one(National park) and then with the dem file (Zonal Statistics as table) create a .dbf table . so from this table i have to select the park with the highest Range. so after that i should export just this layer(with the highest Range) with all the original attribute. so if you can help about the steps?

Comment: Can you use arcpy module? And do you that workflow to be automatic?

Comment: yes i have arcpy, but i don't know about workflow...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32996/discussion-between-saeed-and-david-p).